# zend framework2 Zf-OAuth2 issue

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to use zf-oauth2 module for zendframework2 installed from 
(https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-oauth2) and it seems configured properly but unfortunately I am not getting exact URL which I need to hit.

I tried calling URL like http --auth testclient:testpass -f POST http:///oauth grant_type=client_credentials but it didn't work as I am getting 404 error in response.
So, i am just wandering if this is correct URL or is there is any other way of calling this.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
First make sure that you have indeed enabled the oauth module 'ZF\OAuth2'.
then use this Url
http --auth testclient:testpass -f POST http://yourapp.domain.com/oauth grant_type=client_credentials
This all assumes that you have testclient registered with testpass
If you have follwed correctly but still having problems please post your config
```